# Make Git commit open editor in fullscreen

Tags: git, sublimetext, git-bash, git-commit

Pretty simple, I have a Git commit template that does not look proper when sublime opens in small window by default. I want sublime to open on commits in full screen (window, not sublime's full screen mode). Is there a flag or hook or something to do this?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git

Answer (score 3):

This is a question about Sublime, not git. Git simply runs configured editor and doesn't interact with it; it even doesn't know if the editor opens text or GUI window.

And no, Sublime cannot do that. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1448) about adding a command line option but it's still open.